# Counta(filter()) formula not working as expected

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a COUNTA() formula with certain filters in it. However, the formula is not giving me the result that I expect. If I put my raw data in a pivot table, this is what the result looks like:

[image]

However, if I try to use `counta()` to replicate this, all results show up as 1:

[image]

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(ROW($A:$A)=1,"Appointment Fixed",               //gives a label to the first row
IF(ISBLANK($A:$A),"",                              //handles blank values
COUNTA(FILTER('Raw Data'!$F:$F,                    //the data i want to count
'Raw Data'!$E:$E="platinumTravelCreditCard",       //first filter
('Raw Data'!$H:$H="Approve")+('Raw Data'!$H:$H=""),//second filter: this is an either/or filter
'Raw Data'!$F:$F,$A:$A,                            //third filter
'Raw Data'!$S:$S,"Appointment Fixed")))))          //last filter
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get with this. Let me know if I need to add any more details.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for this with the countifs formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW($A:$A)=1,"Appointment Fixed",IF(ISBLANK($A:$A),"",if(COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!$E:$E,"platinumTravelCreditCard",'Raw Data'!$F:$F,$A:$A,'Raw Data'!$S:$S,"Appointment Fixed",'Raw Data'!$H:$H,"Approve")+COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!E:E,"platinumTravelCreditCard",'Raw Data'!$F:$F,$A:$A,'Raw Data'!$S:$S,"Appointment Fixed",'Raw Data'!$H:$H,"")=0,"",COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!$E:$E,"platinumTravelCreditCard",'Raw Data'!$F:$F,$A:$A,'Raw Data'!$S:$S,"Appointment Fixed",'Raw Data'!$H:$H,"Approve")+COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!E:E,"platinumTravelCreditCard",'Raw Data'!$F:$F,$A:$A,'Raw Data'!$S:$S,"Appointment Fixed",'Raw Data'!$H:$H,"")))))
```